# How to get a nice plot of the following region?

Tags: plotting, regions, style

Consider the region

```
foutDetAnnular = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 20}}, 5];
finDetAnnular = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 20}}, 2];
reg = RegionDifference[foutDetAnnular, finDetAnnular];
```

I would like to make a nice plot with this region. However, my attempt is not nice:

```
Region[Style[reg, Blue, Opacity[0.3]], Axes -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> {Thickness[0.03]}, LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, 20]},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", 
 ViewPoint -> {0.7, -0.25, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 24, Bold, Black], 
   Style["y", 24, Bold, Black], Style["z", 24, Bold, Black]}, 
 Boxed -> True]
```

[image]

Namely, there is no explicit indication of the inner and outer circles (by black lines). If adding the option `EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.01], Black, Opacity -> 0.1]]` which works for the geometries with simple edges (e.g. for a parallelepiped) I get an even worse view:

[image]

**Edit**

I have also tried the following option:

```
Show[Region[
  Style[reg[[2]][[1]], Blue, Opacity[0.3], 
   EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.01], Black, Opacity -> 0.1]]]], 
 Region[Style[reg[[2]][[2]], White, Opacity[1], 
   EdgeForm[Directive[Thickness[0.01], Black, Opacity -> 1]]]]]
```

However, it does not display properly the internal of the smaller cylinder (it should be white):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

foutDetAnnular = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 20}}, 5];
finDetAnnular = Cylinder[{{0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 20}}, 2];
reg = RegionDifference[foutDetAnnular, finDetAnnular];

Show[
 Region[
  Style[reg, Blue, Opacity[0.3]],
  (*Axes->True,*)
  AxesStyle -> {Thickness[0.03]},
  LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, 20]},
  AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic",
  ViewPoint -> {0.7, -0.25, 1},
  AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 24, Bold, Black], 
    Style["y", 24, Bold, Black], Style["z", 24, Bold, Black]}(*,
  Boxed->True*)],
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1], Black}], Transparent, 
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 20}}, 2],
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, 10}, {0, 0, 20}}, 5]}]]
```

[image]